# Terraform long term lock

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using Terraform 0.12 with the remote state in an S3 bucket with DynamoDB locking.

It seems that a common pattern for Terraforming automation goes more or less like this:

1. `terraform plan -out=plan`
2. [review plan]
3. `terraform apply plan`

But then, maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, there's no guarantee other `terraform apply` invocations haven't updated the infrastructure between 1 and 3 above.

I know locking will prevent a concurrent run of `terraform apply` while another one is running (and locking is enabled) but can I programmatically grab a "long term locking" so the effective workflow looks like this?

1. [something to the effect of...] "terraform lock"
2. `terraform plan -out=plan`
3. [review plan]
4. `terraform apply plan`
5. [something to the effect of...] "terraform release lock"

Are there any other means to "protect" infrastructure from `concurrent/interdependant` updates that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this as long as you are only worrying about the state file changing.

If you provide a plan output file to apply and the state has changed since then Terraform will error before making any changes, complaining that the saved plan is stale.

As an example:

```
$ cat <<'EOF' >> main.tf
> resource "random_pet" "bucket_suffix" {}
> 
> resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
>   bucket = "example-${random_pet.bucket_suffix.id}"
>   acl    = "private"
> 
>   tags = {
>     ThingToChange = "foo"
>   }
> }
> EOF
$ terraform init
# ...
$ terraform apply
# ...
$ $ sed -i 's/foo/bar/' main.tf
$ terraform plan -out=plan
# ...
$ sed -i 's/bar/baz/' main.tf
$ terraform apply
# ...
$ terraform apply plan
Error: Saved plan is stale

The given plan file can no longer be applied because the state was changed by
another operation after the plan was created.
```

What it won't do is fail if something outside of Terraform has changed anything. So if instead of applying Terraform again with `baz` as the tag for the bucket I had changed the tag on the bucket via the AWS CLI or the AWS console then Terraform would have happily changed it back to `bar` on the apply with the stale plan.

Comment: Yes, that I learned after some tests.  It covers **some** cases, although in a kindof surprising "optimistic locking" fashion, but not all of them, due to the implications from [Terraform's #2361](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2361#issuecomment-544476862)